# Can't log in to any SE site using Yahoo OpenID

Tags: support, login

I would have asked this on Meta, except that I can't log in there, which is the problem I'm trying to report in the first place.

When I try to login to any SE site using Yahoo's OpenID, I get the following error:

```
The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information 
did not match. Assertion endpoint info: 
ClaimedIdentifier: http://***
ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://*** (same one)
ProviderEndpoint: https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth 
OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs: Discovered endpoint info: [{ 
ClaimedIdentifier: https:***
ProviderLocalIdentifier: https://***
ProviderEndpoint: https://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid/op/auth
OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon },]
```

I tried removing the offending ID and adding it again, but without success.

Apparently, the last time I successfully logged in was the 4th of February.

Comment: I would appreciate vote to close -> move to meta rather than downvotes...

Comment: Are you logged into your yahoo openId? What happens when you use the full URL in the openId url field of the login form (under more login options)?

Comment: Now, I appreciate you may not be able to comment here - but you should be able to on the original on SO...

Answer (score 4):

I've resolved a problem, here is the story:

Yahoo offers several identities for a user, including in form of http://flickr.com/... Which I have used to login to SO. They apparently figured out that they shouldn't use http somewhere between February and now, and fail authentication whenever someone tries to authenticate with it. It also remembers which ID was used for which site.

End result was that I couldn't fix issue from SO side, because when I try to add different (yahoo) ID, Yahoo figures that it's not the one remembered, swithes to http one, and then fails. There is a setting on the Yahoo side where I could forget bound ID's so that way I could setup different one and login again.

Comment: A direct link to "the Yahoo side" would be helpful.

Comment: +1 How did you resolve this? I see no option to change my OpenID url. It is still http://flickr.com and yahoo offers no option to remove/update this. I have multiple OpenID identifiers, but using a different one also gives the same error. Yahoo wants me to use http: // flickr.com and SO complains about https: // flickr.com.

Comment: First you need to add an OpenId in Account Info > Sign-In and Security >  Manage/Create your OpenID. Then go to Account Info > Sign-In and Security > Manage App and Website Connections. There you can remove SO sites authorizations. You also need a computer with a valid SO session that you can use to add your new OpenID. When you try to login next time, yahoo will ask you what ID to use for a site, and you choose non-flickr one.

Comment: I also ran into this problem, and it was also related to http vs https with a flickr openid url.  I wasn't able to log in to SO at all.  Deleting one of the SO sites (serverfault) from the "Manage App and Website Connections" page (https://api.login.yahoo.com/WSLogin/V1/unlink) did the trick.  OpenID seems needlessly complex…